# Passing Parameters to Selector action

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, parameters, selector

I am in a situation where I think I am close to solving, but maybe not.

I have a tableview of custom tableview cells.

Currently each tableviewcell has 3 uibuttons, accessing them and giving them functionality is no problem.

One of the 3 buttons I'm having problems with. The button pushes the user from the current navigation controller to a webview controller, but I want the webview controller to be the http address the current tableview cell is holding.

Heres a small snippit of the code I'm using.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";

    SearchTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SearchTableCell class]])
            {
                cell = (SearchTableCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    Player *event = [_party.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.EventTitle.text = event.name;
    cell.EventDescription.text = event.description;
    cell.EventStartTime.text = event.start_date;
    cell.EventEndTime.text = event.end_date;
    cell.EventTicketURL = event.ticketURL;

    NSString *string = event.ticketURL;

    [cell.buyTicketOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToTicketURL:string) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[cell.AddEventOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    return cell;
}




- (void) pushToTicketURL:(NSString *)string
{

    UIViewController *webViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    webViewController.title = @"Tickets";
    UIWebView *uiWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,370)];

    [uiWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:string]]];

    [webViewController.view addSubview:uiWebView];
    [uiWebView release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Button pressed");
}
```

I have seen some other reviews on the same question but like I said, I just need to pass one parameter to a selector, I understand that is not possible, but what other ways can I go about this problem?

Maybe my question is badly worded :/.

Any help will be great :)

EDIT: I understand `[cell.buyTicketOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToTicketURL:string) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` gives errors. But what work around can I code to do what I want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While you can not pass the URL directly to the selector, you can pass the button itself. So my suggestion would be to tag button according to your cell row and create action like this:

```
void goToAddress: (id) sender {
   UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
   if (button.tag == ..) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Then, in that method you can "look up" URL from the cell with the number equal to tag of the button.

Other than that, I am fairly sure it's impossible to pass custom parameters or more than one parameter in button's selector. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I took your advice and found a link right to the code to do exactly what you said. It worked :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my reputation does not allow me to comment on other answers. jsetting32, the snippet of the code you provided is indeed great and is even better way of doing it, than doing tags. Great job ^^
Regarding the argument below, Rob Napier made a good point. I'd actually use his approach with large structures of data, as it's much more organized. But since you ended up using superview instead of tags, I'd say not to change anything. It is great as-is!

Answer (score 5):

You just need `:` when passing parameter to a selector if you need to pass one parameter.

```
[cell.buyTicketOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToTicketURL:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Basically `:` means you are passing an arguement to the selector and on the receiving end you could define your selector method with the object.

Comment: I didn't know that.  That's neat.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: What makes you think that it does not serve the purpose in solving the problem? This place is to the help in issues not to write all the code, OP had issue in passing parameter to a selector if you have read the question carefully.

Answer (score 4):

Refering to fDmitry's response,

Here's the full code I used for his explanation. It works phenomally :). Thank you to the Omar Abdelhafith, whose link helped me, and fDmitry for getting me on the right track :)

```
-(void)pushToTicketURL:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    UIView *view = button.superview; //Cell contentView
    SearchTableCell *cell = (SearchTableCell *)view.superview;
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.EventTitle.text); //Cell Text

    UIViewController *webViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    webViewController.title = cell.EventTitle.text;
    [webViewController.title sizeWithFont:10];
    UIWebView *uiWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,370)];

    [uiWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:cell.EventTicketURL]]];

    [webViewController.view addSubview:uiWebView];
    [uiWebView release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

This snippet of code helped me so much and hope it helps anyone else whose falls into the same problem :).

Comment: Ah, you stuck the data onto the cell itself. I'd gotten in my mind that each button needed a separate URL. Your approach here is just fine, and very easy to maintain.

Comment: this is kind of fragile -- it is relying on the view hierarchy of the button

Answer (score 1):

@fDmitry's approach isn't bad, and but there are better ways in modern ObjC. Using associated objects, you can attach arbitrary objects (i.e. your URL) to other objects (i.e. your button). You can the ask the sender (the button) for the URL and process it. Here's one way to do it:

```
// Create a category. The "MY" is just a prefix for your namespace
@interface UIButton (MYURLAdditions)
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSURL *MYURL;
@end

// Add the information with a associated object

#import <objc/runtime.h>
@implementation (MYURLAdditions)

static char MYURLKey;
- (NSURL *)MYURL {
  return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &MYURLKey);
}

- (void)setMYURL:(NSURL *)URL {
  objc_setAssociatedObject(obj, &MYURLKey, URL, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
```

With that, after importing your category, you can call `[button setMYURL:]` to set the URL on the button. You can then use `[sender MYURL]` to fetch it in the IBAction.

Comment: Which way is BETTER? I actually have just completed the task by using fDmitry's idea and found several links that allowed me to implement his pseudo comment :). But is your solution more efficient? I would like to try to do your way too but is it necessary, to go the path your suggesting? And when you mean more modern, do you mean Apple developers typically go with your way? Thanks for your insight :)

Comment: The judge of "better" is maintainability and readability here. Doing it with a tag puts the list of URLs in the IBAction. Using associated objects puts the logic at the point that you create the view. Associated objects remove the need for a mapping of "random number" (tag) to URL because they directly tie the view to the URL. In most cases that's easier to read and maintain. But this doesn't mean tags are wrong if they're working well (tags have the advantage of being settable in IB). Efficiency at this level is irrelevant; do what makes your code easy to understand.

Comment: When I say "modern," I mean "since 10.6 and iPhoneOS 3.1." So, within the last 4 years or so. If you maintain things older than that (as I do), then associated objects may not be available.

Comment: Ahh I gotcha, so I imagine something like an iPhone 3 using my code wouldn't work?

Comment: iPhone 3G can run up to iOS 4, so that would be fine. iPhoneOS was the name of iOS prior to iOS 4. (There was never a device called "iPhone 3.")

Comment: ... and the original iPhone can run up to iPhoneOS 3.1.1, so you can still support all devices with this.